# How to prove $A = \log 201 - \frac{201}{200}*\log 2 - 2 > 0$ without using a calculator?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I found a problem online about comparing 2 numbers. I tried doing it the logarithm way and reached this point, but I'm not sure if it's possible to prove that A > 0 without using a calculator.

**EDIT: Log has base 10.**

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: what base are are you using? base 10?

Comment: I assume you mean log base 10. For log bsse e it is also true but not as borderline. If you mean log base 10 you should say that in question.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, it's base 10. I just updated it! Thank you!

Comment: @jim yes it's base 10 sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
A &=\log 201 - \frac{201}{200}\log 2 - 2\\
&=\log 201 - \frac{201}{200}\log 2 - \log 100\\
&=\log \frac{201}{100}-\frac12 \frac{201}{100}\log 2\\
\end{align*}

Now define $f(x)=\log x-\frac x2\log 2$. You can easily check that $f''(x)$ is negative on its domain (so $f$ is concave). Now since $f(2)=f(4)=0$, the continuous $f(x)$ must be positive for $2<x<4$.

Comment: That's so clever!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are very much welcome! :-)